# How to investigate possibly dead-locked threads in w3wp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis, async-await

**NOTE**: This is an attempt to describe a complex issue. I would provide more details as required.

In a very simple ASP MVC application (created specifically to troubleshoot the issue), certain http requests don't complete. The browser tools show the request in **pending status** and no exceptions are raised on the server side.

I have tracked the issue to a line of code with the await keyword.

```
await SendJsonResponse(context, StartJsonPayload);
```

The implementation of the SendJsonResponse writes to the HttpResponse stream. When I have the debugger attached and I add a break point to the line following the await, it never gets hit.

With multiple browser windows open, I used the Debug Diagnostic Tool along with Process Explorer. From the Debug Diagnostic Tools dump file, I identified certain threads that seemed to be hung and when I use Process explorer, the problematic threads seem to all have the same following stack:

```
usp10.dll+0x8580
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x6c0
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x4a8
wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x42a
ntdll.dll!TpAlpcRegisterCompletionList+0x7f8b
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x15
kernel32.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43
kernel32.dll!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
clr.dll+0x4187
```

Here is the full stack trace from the Debug Diagnostic tool of the same thread.

```
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+15 
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+98 
kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+75 
kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+12 
iiscore+15cc7 
iiscore+17a96 
iiscore+18e66 
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ExplicitFlush+6e 
webengine4!MgdExplicitFlush+24 
clr!PInvokeStackImbalanceHelper+22 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)+4c 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)+4c 
[[InlinedCallFrame]] 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()+1a 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()+1a 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean, Boolean)+a8 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()+17 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()+17 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[], Int32, Int32)+3e 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)+65 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)+65 
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.DelegatingStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)+41 
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)+3e 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerResponse.Write(System.ArraySegment`1<Byte>)+67 
mscorlib_ni+388730 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.ResponseExtensions.End(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.IResponse, System.String)+db 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.SendJsonResponse(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostContext, System.String)+d1 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection+<ProcessStartRequest>d__f.MoveNext()+17e 
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)+17 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+a7 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+16 
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()+5b 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<.cctor>b__6(System.Object)+26 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext+<>c__DisplayClass7.<Post>b__6()+10 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(System.Action)+5c 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper+<>c__DisplayClass9.<QueueAsynchronous>b__7(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+d 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()+35 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()+2e 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)+15 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+a7 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+16 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)+cb 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)+b3 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()+7 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+149 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()+5 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
```

My questions are:

1. I have a feeling that I have a dead-lock at hand, is that the case? Is there anything    in the stack traces that point to the fact?
2. What tools/techniques can I use to further investigate the issue?

Any suggestions that help investigate the issue are welcome. Please, suggest possible techniques/tools as well.

Comment: Attach to w3wp with visual studio, break all threads and look to see if there is a deadlock ...

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you for the suggestion. In Visual Studio, it does show threads that are in questionable state but I cannot establish, with certainty, that they are in-fact dead-locked. What should I be looking for in VS?

Comment: In vs you can see where the threads are stopped and then see if they are in a wait or something ... anyway you have much more info available that in dump file like current variable values ...

Comment: @UmairIshaq: This is a common problem if your code is calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` further up the call stack. I don't see that in the stack trace for the thread you posted, but it's worth checking the source code to see if that's happening.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I am working on an OSS project and this issue is related to it. Is there anyway I could pick your brain about this offline, please? There are tons of details that might be relevant and typing them may not be the most suitable method.

Comment: @UmairIshaq: I encourage people to ask questions publicly (i.e., on Stack Overflow); this helps others with the same questions learn as well. However, I do provide consulting services if necessary (and I do charge for it); you can contact me from [my web page](http://stephencleary.com).

Comment: @StephenCleary Like I mentioned, this is for an OSS project and I am going to document the whole thing on SO. However, the complexity of the issue leaves me fumbling for an accurate description, right now. I need help getting to the root of the problem.

Comment: @UmairIshaq: I'm a big believer in OSS (currently contributing to >12 projects), but I just don't have time to take on another right now. SO not only helps other questioners, but also spreads the answering work out (there are a good number of async/await folks on here now).